# video not taking 100% width and height of container

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="wallpaper-container">
        <div class="wallpaper-media wallpaper-image native">
           <!-- <img src="video/space.jpg"> -->
        </div>
        <div class="wallpaper-media wallpaper-video animated">
            <video loop muted autoplay>
                <source src="video/space.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="video/space.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="video/space.ogv" type="video/ogg">
            </video>
      </div>
 </div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
body  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wallpaper-video  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

video  {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

basically i wanted the video to cover 100% of my screen , but it does't , can somebody explain why ? the way it looks in chrome is , as follow:

[image]

As you can see , the vedio is not taking the 100% width of the container , now of couse the below styles are working:

```
.wallpaper-video  {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
```

I.E. the container does take `100vh` and `100vw` , but somehow the video will not take 100% `width` and `height`.

Also the is a horizontal scroll, which is highly undesirable. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Well the desired result was to have the video to be 100% width and 100%  height , now of course if you set the following CSS:

```
video  {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

the video is going to maintain it aspect ratio(a there is going to be white space left as a result) , i believe this behavior is different from an image as an image can be stretched to 100% width and height even though it would look disfigured , so the solution when using a video element would be to use the following style:

```
video  {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

now it will take 100% width of the container.

P.S. Also set the container to `overflow:hidden` just so to hide the part of the video that might overflow.